# Grails 3 and I18n from Database

Tags: grails, ehcache

I'm following the hints from Graeme Rocher (http://graemerocher.blogspot.ch/2010/04/reading-i18n-messages-from-database.html) to store and read out i18n in/to database. This works perfectly in Grails 2.3.6 but I'm updating to Grails 3.0 and getting following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:75) ~[grails-core-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:53) ~[grails-core-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1591) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1559) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'cacheableMappingLocations': : Error creating bean with name 'messageCache': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageCache': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1301) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageCache': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1044) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:859) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:790) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:436) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:186) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1105) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:969) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1286) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.grails.spring.beans.factory.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.instantiate(OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:89) ~[grails-core-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1092) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V
    at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.<init>(EhCacheFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075) ~[springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:51)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:335)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:324)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at easyrent.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'cacheableMappingLocations': : Error creating bean with name 'messageCache': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageCache': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:75)
    at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'cacheableMappingLocations': : Error creating bean with name 'messageCache': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageCache': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageCache': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:859)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:436)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:969)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1286)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.grails.spring.beans.factory.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.instantiate(OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1092)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(J)V
    at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean.<init>(EhCacheFactoryBean.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 54 more
```

resource.groovy looks following:

```
import one.myapp.DatabaseMessageSource
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean    


beans = {
    bcrypt(BCrypt)    

    messageCache(EhCacheFactoryBean) {
     timeToLive = 864000 // eq 10 days
    }

    messageSource(DatabaseMessageSource) {
        messageCache = messageCache
    }
}
```

DatabaseMessageSource.groovy looks like:

```
package one.myapp    

import one.myapp.TextModule
import net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource
import net.sf.ehcache.Element
import java.text.MessageFormat    

class DatabaseMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource {

    Ehcache messageCache
    def messageBundleMessageSource    

    @Override
    protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {    

        def key = "${code}_${locale.language}_${locale.country}_${locale.variant}";
        def format = messageCache.get(key)?.value;
        if ( ! format) {

            //println("Get From DB: " + code)
            def message = TextModule.findByCode(code)
            if (message) {    

                def text    

                switch(locale) {    

                    case Locale.FRENCH:
                    text = message.valueFr
                    break    

                    case Locale.ENGLISH:
                    text = message.valueEn
                    break    

                    default: 
                    text = message.valueDe
                    break
                }    

                if ( ! text || text.length() == 0) { 
                    text = message.valueDe
                }    

                text = text?.replaceAll("\n", "<br />")    

                format = new MessageFormat(text, locale)
            } else {
                format = new MessageFormat(code, locale)
            }
            messageCache.put(new Element(key, format))
        } else {
            format = (MessageFormat) format
        }
        return format
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when setting up a custom messageSource in Grails 3.1.9. The issue was resolved by excluding 'ehcache-core' from the hibernate-ehcache dependency which uses an older version of ehcache.

```
compile ("org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache") { exclude module: 'ehcache-core'}
```

Add the above to your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Given the stacktrace, this looks like a version mismatch between Spring caching and Ehcache.
`EhCacheFactoryBean` extends Ehcache's `CacheConfiguration` object. The method `setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(long maxEntriesLocalHeap)` has been present in the API of Ehcache since [version 2.6.0](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.6.0/net/sf/ehcache/config/CacheConfiguration.java#CacheConfiguration.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap%28long%29) (and not in [latest 2.5.x](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.5.7/net/sf/ehcache/config/CacheConfiguration.java#CacheConfiguration))

So you will need to find what pulls an Ehcache verison older than 2.6.0 in your application's classpath and remove / ignore that dependency in favour of a more recent Ehcache version.